# Change Search URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to change my WordPress search URLs to some URLs user friendly.

My current search url looks like this:

```
?s=fim&post_type%5B%5D=post&post_type%5B%5D=blog
```

Where I filter the search and get only posts from post_type: post and blog.

I've already tried this two methods:

`functions.php`

```
function wpb_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpb_change_search_url' );
```

and

`.htaccess`

```
# Change WordPress search URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1/? [NC,R,L]
```

But those two redirect the page and make me loose the post_type filter.

Any idea how I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function foo_modify_query_order( $query ) {

    if( is_admin() )
        return;

    if( is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $post_type = array('resource');
        $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
        $query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'foo_modify_query_order' );
```

this query will filter post from post type 'blog' and 'post'.

Comment: Work fine! Thank you